# How to write an update query in access and not import null values?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table in Access that need to be updated with data from another table. The table with the data to update contains fields that may be null. I need an update query that will not overwrite my primary table with null values from the other table.

I have tried this query

```
Update tblEmployees
Inner Join tblPAF ON tblEmployees.EmployeeID = tblPAF.EmployeeID
Set tblEmployee.DepartmentID = tblPAF.NewDeptID, tblEmployeeHourlyRate = tblPAF.HourlyRate, tblEmployee.ShiftID = tblPAF.ShiftID
Where((tblPAF.NewDeptID Is Not Null, OR tblPAFHourlyRate Is Not Null, OR tblPAF.NewDeptID Is Not Null))
```

I apologize if you have answered this in a previous post but any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The general approach in this situation will be to use the NZ function to update the column with the other table's value if it is not null, otherwise set the column to "itself".
i.e.

```
Update tblEmployees
Inner Join tblPAF ON tblEmployees.EmployeeID = tblPAF.EmployeeID
Set tblEmployees.DepartmentID = NZ(tblPAF.NewDeptID, tblEmployees.DepartmentID),
tblEmployees.HourlyRate = NZ(tblPAF.HourlyRate, tblEmployees.HourlyRate),
tblEmployees.ShiftID = NZ(tblPAF.ShiftID, tblEmployees.ShiftID)
Where tblPAF.NewDeptID Is Not Null 
OR tblPAF.HourlyRate Is Not Null 
OR tblPAF.NewDeptID Is Not Null
```

Note: There seem to be a few inconsistencies in the code you've posted e.g. shouldn't be a comma after your `Is Not Null` clauses, I think?